# Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: app, data-explorer

[image: SEDE]

### About

Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) is an open source tool for running arbitrary queries against public data from the Stack Exchange network. Features include collaborative query editing for all graduated and public beta Stack Exchange sites.

This app is used to allow Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow users to [authenticate and log into SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353406/stack-exchange-data-explorer-login-is-changing).

### Contact

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer

### Code

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer